# Titan with hbase on windows 7 configuarations

Tags: java, hadoop, cygwin, hbase, titan

I am struggling to set up titan with Hbase .Below are the stteps I followed,

1. Downloaed titan-hbase
2. downloaded cygwin
3. Installed Hbase ( referred this http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html)
4. Hbase in running in cygwin .
5. 5.Titan is running on my windows and basic gremlin console is coming up.

Now I want to load Hbase as storage in titan . 
I am not understanding how to configure in titan so that it will map to hbase (which running in cygwin shell (command prompt).

I am trying something like this on my titan console

```
gremlin> TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.open('conf\titan-hbase-es.properties');
```

I am getting below error

> ```
> Could not instantiate implementation: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager
> ```
>
> Display stack trace? [yN]
>
> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation:
> ```
>
> com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.instantiate(Backend.java:355)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:367)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:311)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.(Backend.java:121)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1173)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.(StandardTitanGraph.java:75)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:40)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:29)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$open.call(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:56)
>           at groovysh_evaluate$run.call(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:67)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter$evaluate.call(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:152)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:114)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$0.call(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:88)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:100)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:66)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.(Console.java:57)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.(Console.java:70)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.main(Console.java:96)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.instantiate(Backend.java:344)
>           ... 63 more Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.PermanentStorageException: Failed
>   to create directory D:\GraphDBTitan\titan-all-0.4.4\bin\conf
>   itan-hbase-es.properties for local storage.
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.DirectoryUtil.getOrCreateDataDirectory(DirectoryUtil.java:24)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.common.LocalStoreManager.(LocalStoreManager.java:29)
>           at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.berkeleyje.BerkeleyJEStoreManager.(BerkeleyJEStoreManager.java:36)
>           ... 68 more

Please someone help me to fix this .

Comment: Try to install in linux machine, if you don't have one, use a virtual machine inside windows. 
With Windows+Cygwin you will always stumble upon multiple compatibility issues,
Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Like remis said in the comments, installing on a Linux machine would reduce the compatibility issues. If you decide to give it a go this article contains the steps to get you started with Titan on HBase: http://blog.trackerbird.com/content/setting-up-titan-1-0-apache-hbase/.

Answer (score 0):

I found the main issue under the `cygwin` is with the `$(pwd)` expression, change it to `$(cygpath -aw $(pwd))` please.